# Need help with SQL join to a function

Tags: sql-server, triggers, user-defined-functions

I am trying to enter the following to an UPDATE trigger of QuoteItem:

```
UPDATE QuoteItem
SET List = StyleItem.List, CostFactor = StyleItem.CostFactor, Cost = NULL
FROM dbo.fn_GetQuoteItemListPrice(QuoteItem.ItemId, QuoteItem.RoomId) 
    AS StyleItem
CROSS JOIN (QuoteItem JOIN INSERTED ON 
    QuoteItem.QuoteItemId = INSERTED.QuoteItemId)
WHERE (INSERTED.List IS NULL) AND (INSERTED.ItemId IS NOT NULL)
```

I get the follwoing error:

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure QuoteItem_UPDATE, Line 6
The multi-part identifier "QuoteItem.ItemId" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure QuoteItem_UPDATE, Line 6
The multi-part identifier "QuoteItem.RoomId" could not be bound.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/0ae9c2b9-71ee-4be6-b182-c9b531076b1c) by Naomi Nosonovsky:

```
UPDATE QuoteItem
SET List = StyleItem.List, CostFactor = StyleItem.CostFactor, Cost = NULL
FROM QuoteItem JOIN INSERTED AS INSERTED ON QuoteItem.QuoteItemId =
    INSERTED.QuoteItemId
    CROSS APPLY dbo.fn_GetQuoteItemListPrice(QuoteItem.ItemId, QuoteItem.RoomId)
        AS StyleItem 
WHERE (INSERTED.List IS NULL) AND (INSERTED.ItemId IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE QuoteItem
SET List = StyleItem.List, CostFactor = StyleItem.CostFactor, Cost = NULL
FROM dbo.fn_GetQuoteItemListPrice(xx.ItemId, xx.RoomId) 
    AS StyleItem
CROSS JOIN (QuoteItem JOIN INSERTED ON 
    QuoteItem.QuoteItemId = INSERTED.QuoteItemId)  xx
WHERE (INSERTED.List IS NULL) AND (INSERTED.ItemId IS NOT NULL)
```

Try the change I made above, assigning a table alias xx and referencing that instead..

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure QuoteItem_UPDATE, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near 'xx'.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have SQL open, but try adding     ON 1=1 after the xx

Comment: Also, why do you need the cross join, could you not reference the ItemID and RoomId directly from the INSERTED table?

Comment: cuz as u can see it's a multi value udf, i.e. returns table

Comment: and the cross join i need cuz i wanna update QuoteItem's affected rows - INSERTED table cannot be update.
and as u can guess the function does some calcs as well, that's y i need it this way